# HTML Parsing using Jsoup.Jar

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://reviews.opentable.com/0938/9/reviews.htm").get();
    Element part = doc.body();
    Elements parts = part.getElementsByTag("span");
    String attValue;
    String html;
    for(Element ent : parts)
    {
        if(ent.hasAttr("class"))
        {
            attValue = ent.attr("class");
            if(attValue=="BVRRReviewText description")
            {
                System.out.println("\n");
                html=ent.text();
                System.out.println(html);
            }
        }
    }
```

Am using Jsoup.jar for the above program.

I am accessing the webpage and my aim is to the print the text that is found within the tag `<span class="BVRRReviewText description">text</span>`.

But nothing is getting printed as output. There is no contents added to the `String html` in the program. But `attValue` is getting all the attribute values of the span tag.

Where must I have went wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(attValue=="BVRRReviewText description")
```

should be

`if(attValue.equals("..."))` surely?

This is Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`attValue=="BVRRReviewText description"`

for

`attValue.matches("...")`